# SQL Server database partitioning purge job failed with an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning, sql-server-agent

We have a SQL Server Agent job that executes package to purge partition file and filegroup older than 25 month. The job was running fine however it failed this month with following error:

> The operation cannot be performed on a database with database snapshots or active DBCC replicas

I checked the SQL Server logs and there weren't any DBCC process running during time. I cannot figure out why it is throwing out database snapshot/active DBCC replicas error.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 - clustered instance.

SSIS Package steps:

1. Find out oldest partition to delete
2. Drop Archive table if exists
3. Get date to delete partition (Using table --- sys.partition_range_values 
   Where boundary_id = 1)
4. Create Archive tables
5. Switch partition 2 to Archive tables
6. Drop Archive tables
7. Merge partitions
8. Remove file and filegroup

Comment: Do you have any database snapshots for this database?  What does `SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE source_database_id IS NOT NULL` return?

Comment: It returns 0 rows.

Comment: Update:- It's resolved. Job did purge the data from the oldest partition however it failed on last step of SSIS package where it removes file and filegroup so I deleted file and filegroup by executing T-SQL of last step of the package.